# Is the conventional self "conventional" in the same way as dharmas are?

Tags: self, dharmas, conventional-truth

Is the conventional self "conventional" in the same way as dharmas are?

So if the conventionality of dharmas means that they arise and disappear each moment, or that they don't exist from their own side, or that they leave no trace of themselves, or that they always have parts (etc., etc.) does the same apply to the conventional self?

I understand that both lack "substance": but does that mean the same thing here?

**I'm interested in anyone having said "no".**

Comment: There is no agreement as to what are Dharmas and a conventional 'self', if it is conventional & normal then what is the mystery. We have also had plenty of questions dealing with the words 'self' & 'emptiness', you should search for those because i doubt anybody will bother repeating the answers. It's very unclear what it is you are asking because you are mixing various methods of expression, eg notion of a 'conventional self' is entirely foreign to pali litterature.

Comment: likewise the notion of dhammas arising & ceasing every moment, this is also foreign to sutta and is actually reprimandable because it is said that what is called mind, consciousness or intellect arises as one thing & ceases as another.

Comment: "notion of a 'conventional self' is entirely foreign to pali litterature" @Letsbuddhism I agree I don't understand this question, but I think that "conventional" self is for example in the dialog of King Milinda -- where "conventional" is [translated here](https://suttacentral.net/mil3.1.1/en/tw_rhysdavids) as "the designation in common use".

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "dharmas" in the first paragraph -- I thought you meant "doctrines" but I guess you meant "things".

Comment: I think you're glossing "self" to mean "ultimate / substantial / unchanging / etc. self", etc.. it'a pretty standard, but has been pretty conclusively - I think - established as a mistake @Letsbuddhism

Comment: If you agree, maybe it would draw more attention by using the terms *avijja* and *vijja* instead of conventional self and dharmas, that's if I understand your meaning of dharmas. In Theravada, Avijja has a similar meaning to conventional self, and Vijja has a similar meaning to dharmas. Avijja - without the risk of sounding derogatory - is a kind of stupidity or living life with a closed mind. Vijja is the opposite: it's a desire to see the larger frame of reference where situational wisdom arises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Theravada posit the selflessness of phenomena?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/28708/does-theravada-posit-the-selflessness-of-phenomena)

Comment: I think this question is possibly a duplicate of https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/28708/does-theravada-posit-the-selflessness-of-phenomena and https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/28709/if-theravada-doesnt-posit-the-selflessness-of-phenomena-then-how-to-interpret

Comment: @ChrisW as to conventional, i'll give you that but it's a stretch to say that The Buddha taught about the doctrine of self in this way. As to OP You will be surprised as to the amount of delusion in buddhist circles. Don't want to get into details much but afaik the word moment occurs like 1 time in the tipitaka and that in a book of abhidhamma. The conditioned is said to change as it persists and consciousness arising as one thing & ceasing as another. I only post this to show how difficult it is to interpret your question, i neither agree nor disagree with your assertions.

Comment: Afaik It is mostly after 11th century that the doctrine of things arising & ceasing very fast became a popular expression in Theravada due to the comy which is Abhidhammattha-sangaha.

Comment: I said there is a lot of delusion in Buddhist circles in regards to this "no it is not entirely foreign to the pali sutras, not unless lots of monks have been entirely misunderstanding the sutras". I was just using your proposition of monks having a lot misunderstanding [delusion] if that expression is indeed foreign to Sutta and it obviously isn't in the canonical texts, i already explained the origin. I think that you will be surprised to learn how much disagreement there is among monks and commentators if you study more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OP: "Is the conventional self "conventional" in the same way as dharmas
> are?"

In extent Mahayana traditions the selflessness of phenomena and the selflessness of persons is of the same nature and both are posited. They differ only in the object of focus. Further, it is considered critical to understand the selflessness of phenomena in order to achieve the soteriological ends of the Buddha.

In the Theravada, the selflessness of phenomena is not posited and it is treated by some as not germane to the soteriological ends of the Buddha while others insist that positing the selflessness of phenomena is actually a hindrance in that it denies the reality of the objectively existing world. However, it should be noted that *some* [Theravada practitioners here on the site](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45629/13375) seem to have more or less the same understanding of the two selves as Mahayana.

> OP: "So if the conventionality of dharmas means that they arise and
> disappear each moment, or that they don't exist from their own side,
> or that they leave no trace of themselves, or that they always have
> parts (etc., etc.) does the same apply to the conventional self?"

In Mahayana: yes. In Theravada: see above.

> OP: "I understand that both lack "substance": but does that mean the
> same thing here?"

Again see above.

Also, these [questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/28708/does-theravada-posit-the-selflessness-of-phenomena) and [answers](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/28709/if-theravada-doesnt-posit-the-selflessness-of-phenomena-then-how-to-interpret) might be helpful.

Comment: can you please provide a reference for your first paragraph, ideally a very catholic one

Comment: You can find a reference to a Geshe Lharampa stating essentially the same thing in the first link I posted in the answer above. Cheers.

Comment: ok well I was primary interested in more sinitic forms of buddhism cheers

Comment: Yeah, that's hard to give a reference for. I think most of the sinitic traditions would agree, but it will be hard to find a detailed description written in an academic fashion. The Tibetan traditions are the most academic in this sense.

Comment: dwai, I will ask a Tendai monk or scholar. your answer was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding self as a convention:

If you sit down, you have a lap. When you stand up, where is the lap? Where has it gone to?

What a "lap" is, is just a convention, just a like a "fist".

Similarly, a being (*satta*), a person (*puggala*), a chariot (*ratha*) are all conventions. See [SN 5.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn5.10/en/bodhi).

The self (*atta*) can be seen in two forms.

In the first case, when am unenlightened person clings to it, it's simply a mental idea ([Snp 4.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.14.than.html)) in the mind that one clings to.

In the second case, when an enlightened one says "me", "I", "we", "our", "mine", he is just using conventions ([SN 1.25](https://suttacentral.net/sn1.25/en/sujato)).

Even in the first case, it's just a convention too. Why? What you call "self" is somehow pegged to some other concept like your body or your mind or your personality.

So, imagine if you go to the beach and spend a lot of time and effort to build a sand castle. Then someone comes and smashes it. You feel angry and say "why did you smash my sand castle?" "You", "my" and "sand castle" are all conventions. The anger appeared because of clinging.

---

Regarding emptiness:

The concept of "substance" (*svabhava*) comes in the Madhyamaka philosophy of Mahayana. Madhyamaka states that everything is empty of substance, which means it is empty of the meaning that is given to it by the mind. It's not what you think it is.

*Anatta* is the notion that everything is not self. The body, the mind, the five aggregates, mental ideas etc. are all not self.

*Anatta* is a specialized form of emptiness (i.e. everything is empty of a self - [SN 35.85](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.085.than.html)), while the Madhyamaka emptiness is a more generalized form (i.e. everything is empty of the meaning given to it by the mind). Both types of emptiness are covered in [MN 1](https://suttacentral.net/mn1/en/bodhi). So, Theravada has both too, in fact.

The Madhyamaka emptiness is explained by the Pali term *papanca*. If *papanca* is the process of baking, then *svabhava* is the cake. Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39254/471).

In [his commentary to Snp 4.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.14.than.html#fn-1), Ven. Thanissaro explained that the objectification and classification (*papanca*) of the mental idea of the self vs. non-self objects, lead to craving, clinging and suffering. He also explained *papanca* in [his commentary to MN 18](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.018.than.html).

A detailed explanation can be found in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/44535/471).

Comment: yes, similarly. I made that point in the question, and asked if they are in the same way empty. are they?

Comment: @unknown_buddhist The concept of "substance" (*svabhava*) comes in the Madhyamaka philosophy of Mahayana. Madhyamaka states that everything is empty of substance, which means it is empty of the meaning that is given to it by the mind. It's not what you think it is.

Comment: oh, I have definitely heard that anatta means the self lacks a "substance". certainly, anatta has been glossed before as "emptiness of self", just as sunyata has as "lack of self existence"

Comment: Anatta is the notion that everything is not self. Your body, your mind, the five aggregates, mental ideas etc. are all not self.

Comment: so you seem to think "no" they are just similar, not the same, emptiness. that's cool... I'm out of questions now anyway!

Comment: @unknown_buddhist Anatta is a specialized form of emptiness (i.e. everything is empty of a self), while the Madhyamaka emptiness is a more generalized form (i.e. everything is empty of the meaning given to it by the mind). Both types of emptiness are covered in [MN 1](https://suttacentral.net/mn1/en/bodhi). So, Theravada has both too, in fact.

Comment: they mean different things (in Mahayana and Theravada) I believe, but ymmv - legitimately I mean ha!

Comment: @ruben2020 this answer says that Theravada *also* has selflessness of phenomena according to MN 1... does that mean you've changed your mind? Do you now regard the selflessness of phenomena as important to the goals of liberation?

Comment: @YesheTenley What you call "selflessness of phenomena" is called *papanca* (reification or conceptualization or objectification-classification) in Theravada. The mental idea of the self is a type of *papanca* and non-self objects are also *papanca*. Craving is also habit of *papanca*. [Snp 4.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.14.than.html) is very clear that to end suffering, we must end *papanca* by putting an end to the root of *papanca*, which is the thought "I am the thinker" (i.e. the self). Ven. Thanissaro explains this in his footnote.

Comment: see https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/what-is-the-difference-between-theravada-papanca-with-regard-to-objects-and-ma